# Excel VBA script to output TSV is giving leading and trailing double quotes, how can I remove them

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ExportDataTSV()
Dim BCS As Worksheet
Dim Ctrl As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FName As String
Dim insertValues As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set BCS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet2.Name)
Set Ctrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1.Name)

fileDate = Year(Now) & "_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Day(Now) & "_" & Format(Now, "hh")

#If Mac Then
    NameFolder = "documents folder"

    If Int(Val(Application.Version)) > 14 Then
    'You run Mac Excel 2016
    folder = _
    MacScript("return POSIX path of (path to " & NameFolder & ") as string")
    'Replace line needed for the special folders Home and documents
    folder = _
    Replace(SpecialFolder, "/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data", "")
    Else
    'You run Mac Excel 2011
    folder = MacScript("return (path to " & NameFolder & ") as string")
    End If
    
    FName = folder & ":bcs_output.txt"
#Else
    folder = Environ$("userprofile")
    
    FName = folder & "\Documents\bcs_output_" & fileDate & ".txt"
#End If

If Ctrl.Range("D9") = "" Or Ctrl.Range("D10") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter the Scenario Year and Scenario you wish to save and click again", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

Ctrl.Range("D9").Copy
BCS.Range("AS2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Ctrl.Range("D10").Copy
BCS.Range("AT2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Call ClearFile(FName)

With BCS
    
    .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    numrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    numcol = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range("AS1").Value = "scenario_year"
    .Range("AS2:AS" & numrows).FillDown
    .Range("AT1").Value = "scenario"
    .Range("AT2:AT" & numrows).FillDown
    .Range("AU1").Value = "save_date"
    .Range("AU2").Formula = "=NOW()"
    .Range("AU2:AU" & numrows).FillDown
    .Range("AU2:AU" & numrows).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"
    For x = 2 To numrows
        Set rng1 = .Range("A" & x & ":R" & x)
        Set rng2 = .Range("AC" & x & ":AF" & x)
        Set rng3 = .Range("AH" & x & ":AK" & x)
        Set rng4 = .Range("AN" & x & ":AO" & x)
        Set rng5 = .Range("AS" & x & ":AU" & x)
        Set Data = Union(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5)
    
        insertValues = Join2D(ToArray(Data), Chr(9))
        Call ConvertText(FName, insertValues)
    Next x
End With


With BCS
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Select
End With

Ctrl.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Cluster Data saved to " & FName & ", please upload the file here: https://awsfinbi.corp.amazon.com/s/dcgs_abv/submit", vbOKOnly
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function ToArray(rng) As Variant()
    Dim arr() As Variant, r As Long, nr As Long
    Dim ar As Range, c As Range, cnum As Long, rnum As Long
    Dim col As Range

    nr = rng.Areas(1).Rows.Count
    ReDim arr(1 To nr, 1 To rng.Cells.Count / nr)
    cnum = 0
    For Each ar In rng.Areas
        For Each col In ar.Columns
        cnum = cnum + 1
        rnum = 1
        For Each c In col.Cells
            arr(rnum, cnum) = c.Value
            rnum = rnum + 1
        Next c
        Next col
    Next ar

    ToArray = arr
End Function

Public Function Join2D(ByVal vArray As Variant, Optional ByVal sWordDelim As String = " ", Optional ByVal sLineDelim As String = vbNewLine) As String
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aReturn() As String
    Dim aLine() As String
    
    ReDim aReturn(LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1))
    ReDim aLine(LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2))
    
    For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)
            'Put the current line into a 1d array
            aLine(j) = vArray(i, j)
        Next j
        'Join the current line into a 1d array
        aReturn(i) = Join(aLine, sWordDelim)
    Next i
    
    Join2D = Join(aReturn, sLineDelim)
    
End Function

Public Function ClearFile(myfile)

Open myfile For Output As #1: Close #1

End Function
Public Function ConvertText(myfile As String, strTxt As String)

Open myfile For Append As #1
Write #1, strTxt
Close #1

End Function
```

The above functions are what I have strung together from various SO post and googles.  It works to a large degree, but when it creates the txt file with the tab delimiter it gives an output where in the text separator is a single quote. However, the entire line is wrapped in double quotes.  So the output looks something like `"'Field1'\t'Field2'\t'Field3'"` .  That is not a valid TSV format for loading into a database like Redshift due to the double quotes.  I need the double quotes to not be in the file, can anyone identify why it is adding them?  Is there a way to prevent it or a better way to create a tab delimited file output for loading to Redshift?

For further information it MUST be a txt with tab delimiter, I have no control over that requirement.

Comment: You can use the `Replace` function just like you are already doing... `=Replace(sText, "'","")` where `sText` is the name of your variable that has the text.

Comment: I tried `Replace(insertValues, "Chr(34)", "")` and `Replace(insertValues, Chr(34), "")` to no avail.  there is still `"` at the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: `Write` and `Print` do different things when sending content to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement

> Unlike the Print # statement, **the Write # statement inserts commas
> between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written
> to the file**. You don't have to put explicit delimiters in the list.
> Write # inserts a newline character, that is, a carriage
> return-linefeed (Chr(13) + Chr(10) ), after it has written the final
> character in outputlist to the file.

To not add quotes switch to `Print`:

```
Print #1, strTxt
```

Comment: That is interesting; I guess I have to find another way to output to the file then.

Comment: Just use `Print #1, strTxt` instead of `Write #1, strTxt`

Comment: I figured that out after re-reading what you put there, thanks!